# AEM Filter not getting called

Tags: osgi, aem

I have written an AEM filter but it is not getting invoked.
    Do we have to provide some configuration some where also except the class?
    below is the structure, is there anything wrong there?

```
@SlingFilter(label = "ABC", description = "abc", metatype = false, generateComponent = false,
        generateService = true, // True; required for Sling Filters
        order = -8642, //lowest order as per my application
        scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST) 
@Properties({ @Property(label = "Vendor", name = "service.vendor", value = "abc", propertyPrivate = true) })
public class CoursePageFilter implements Filter {
    protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {      
        final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (SlingHttpServletResponse) response;
        final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        final Resource resource = slingRequest.getResource();
        String curPageName = resource.getPath();
        if (resource.getPath().startsWith("/xyz")) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatch = slingRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/abc.html");
                dispatch.forward(slingRequest, slingResponse);
                return;
        }
        // to proceed with the rest of the Filter chain     
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your bundles active? Do you find anything in the logs?

Comment: Can you change your order to positive number? -ve numbers means it will be fire earlier...

Comment: How do you know that it isn't getting invoked? Also, could you please post some sample URLs that you are using for testing this?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint?

Comment: Just as a test please remove 'generateService' and 'generateComponent' from the SlingServlet annotation.